# How to branch wire?

Tags: power, wire

I have thick 16 gauge wire coming from the main power supply that needs to branch out and power several 8x8 LED boards. Each LED board requires only 22 gauge wire for the current it draws. I would like to branch out the thick wire to the thinner wire at regularly spaced intervals, but the only solution I could think of is to break the insulation on the thick wire at several points and solder the thinner wire on as necessary. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: related, if not duplicate: [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/115298/7036),
[this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/140382/7036),
[this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/31433/7036).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something like a T-Tap would fit the bill (see below)

[image: Standard T-Tap]

It consists of two parts: one crimps onto your 22 gauge wire (the male quick disconnect terminal in the image) and the other part crimps onto the 16 gauge wire. This has the added benefit of allowing you to disconnect and re-connect the LED boards at will.